# How to find files in subdirectories and copy it to the folder immediately before the location where the file was found

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, files, directory

I have the following scheme of file directory:

```
.
|-- FOO1
|   `-- p58
|       `-- file1.csv
|-- FOO2
|   `-- p63
|       `-- file2.csv
```

Note that each of the CSV files is located in the subdirectory of FOO or BAR.
What I want to do is to copy it to one directory before it. Resulting in this:

```
.
|-- FOO1
|   `-- file1.csv
|   `-- p58
|       `-- file1.csv
|-- FOO2
|   `-- file2.csv
|   `-- p63
|       `-- file2.csv
```

I tried this but failed:

```
find . -type f -name "*.csv" | grep FOO | xargs -I {} cp {} ..;
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Nice to see a Matter Modeler here! I've helped advertise your question [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62794454#62794454), hopefully that helps get it answered!

Comment: Are you using Linux? (`GNU find`)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Yes, Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU find  you can make use of the option `-execdir` like this:

```bash
find . -type f -name "*.csv" -execdir cp --target-directory=.. {} +
```

From `man find`:

> -execdir command ;
>
> -execdir command {} +
>
> > Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally the  directory  in  which  you started  find.

For that reason I used: `cp --target-directory=..`, if the find command is on `p58` directory using `..` it will place the files under its parent directory `FOO1`.

And about `{} +` I used that in order to be able to pass all matched files `*.csv` from the current directory to the target directory (or parent directory in this case)